# How to split app functions between services class and util classes?

Tags: java, spring, oop

We using spring framework and met a situation like this:

We have service classes, e.g CatalogManager, CourseManager, we now want let them have functions like for example, parseXML.

My question is should I put those methods into each individal class, such as a parseXML method in CatalogManager or CourseManager? Or we should create a XMLUtil class and create methods like parseCatalogXMl and parseCourseXML in this class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `parseXML()` will be doing.

**Case 1:** If all of the `parseXML()` methods are going to do the same thing, then you should have another class that has one `parseXML()` method. Why? It avoids unnecessary repetition, makes it easier to update, and is more easily expandable.

**Case 2:** If all of the `parseXML()` methods will be different (majorly, not just a few lines), it would be easier to implement the method in every class. Why? Trying to combine many different methods into one is complicated and ugly.

**Case  3:** Create a superclass of `CatalogManager` and `CourseManager` that has a `parseXML()` method. Then, if a subclass needs to do something different with this method, it can simply override it.

**Which one should you use?** The final solution is the most preferable as it keeps your code simple, expandable, readable, and updatable, combining the best of the first two approaches. But if the one of the first two cases strictly apply, those should be used instead.

Your class structure would be like this:

```
Manager          // the super class, this implements parseXML().
  CatalogManager // a sub class, overriding parseXML() only if it needs to.
  CourseManager  // same as above.
XMLUtil          // this class is only necessary in case 1.
```

It's your decision in the end. No case is faster than any other, just pick the one you want.